# ATI X 1270 on Packard Bell Dot ma netbook

Tags: drivers, ati

Dont understand why there are no support for this video card. I have to quit using ubuntu because of that!!!

Answer (score 2):

ATI have stopped updating their drivers for older cards, this is the reason there's no driver available for you in 11.04. If you downgrade to Ubuntu 8.10 or 8.04, you should be able to install the older `fglrx` drivers and your card should work.

I've tried myself to get the older drivers working on a newer version of Ubuntu, and it was a nightmare - I wouldn't even bother trying.

Comment: Since these versions of Ubuntu are no longer supported, it would probably be best to find a different operating system (perhaps a different GNU/Linux distribution) that works with a sufficiently old kernel. [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) may be a good place to ask about that.